# move_uploaded_file didn't work on sql server

Tags: php, mysql, sqlsrv

i'm using php for web development. Currently, i've to use sql server as the db for my new project. My problem is, the codes to upload files into the server which i usually apply when using mysql didn't work on sql server. Is there any special function that i've to add when uploading a file on sql server?

btw, here is the code that i usually used and works well on mysql server:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$file=$_FILES['file'];

$fileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileExt=explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){

}else{
    echo"not this type";
}
$fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileName;
if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination)){

header("location:form.php?uploadsuccess");
}
else{
    echo "uploading error";
}
}
?>
```

i would really appreciate for solutions :)

Comment: How is file uploading related to sql/mysql? Where is the MySQL part in your code?

Comment: Are you doing this on localhost? And did you use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form? and Why is your first if else statement in the if empty, you need to move your code thats below your else now into it

Comment: By saying SQL Server, are you referring to Microsoft SQL server?
Do you have an uploads directory in your webapp root? Does your web server have read/write permissions to that directory? Have you checked your web server's logfiles? Look in your PHP configuration to find out where you PHP temp directory is. Can you see any files uploaded to there?

Comment: @kerbholz above are code use to move the photos that i want to upload into the root folder

Comment: @MichaelThompson yes, i'm using Microsoft SQL server. i already create a folder in the root folder as the directory to move the files. sorry but i'm kinda new with Microsoft sql server, are the logfiles is the one that located in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 ?

Comment: @J.Ende yes, i did. here is my form in html looks like:

<html>
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</html>

the if else statement shows that if the condition is applied, it will display nothing, else error message will appear. I've use the same if else statement on a page with mysql server and it works. it just don't work when i use Micosoft sql server

Comment: @atiqahz Did my answer help you?

Comment: @J.Ende nope. like i said, it works on mysql server but not microsoft sql server

Comment: I also tried this myself and for me it works in sql server..

Comment: Don't you get any errors? in cpanel/error_reporting on.. something we can work with

Comment: @J.Ende there are no errors, the successful message also displayed on the page, the problem is my images aren't move into the destination folders ('uploads')

Comment: I don't understand why you talk about sql server, because we are not using databases atm?

Comment: @J.Ende what i mean is, images in xampp root folder do moves into its destination folder, but in inetpub root folder, the images didn't. what i am trying to do is to ensure the images will move into the 'uploads' folder.
sorry if i didn't explain well on about my problem

Comment: I don't think I can more than I have done now, I don't know anything about inetpub and exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know what the problem is in your code. If you used this line `<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` at your form and you are doing this on localhost otherwise it was something with the path. Than try this code I made, if this won't work you should look for errors in maybe you cpanel or turn on error reporting

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

            $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
            $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

            $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

            if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
                if($fileError === 0){
                    if($fileSize < 1000000){
                        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                        $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                        header("location:form.php?uploadsuccess");
                    }else{
                        echo "Your file is too big!";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
                }
            }else{
                echo "You can't upload files of this type!";
            }
       }
```